# Recyclerview inside a Scrollview not calling the Custom Adapter Function (onBindViewHolder)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, custom-adapter

While scrolling the page, onBindViewHolder() is not calling.

mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is not updating the data correctly because of Scrollview. I checked only 3 Checkbox in Recycler. After the loading of 2nd set of data and calling the notifier more checkbox got checked irrelevantly still the data is coming from Model class correctly.

I can't share the code here, because of security reasons.
I already spent a day to fix. Not fixed yet.

Then I tried removing the scrollview, it worked.

I have another few more view to fit inside the scroller. So I added that as a layout and added in the first position of Recycler. It worked. But from fragment whenever I want only that time it should come. Is there any way to fix atleast this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ogande, Thanks. I tried your code. Same thing is happening. So I tried with different solution, as I mentioned in my question.

I removed the scrollview and kept only Recyclerview.

I added two layouts in my Adapter. So whenever I want to add the new layout I am passing a boolean value from the fragment to the adapter as true and at the starting all the position will take default value as false. So `notifychanged()` will reflect the change to the adapter with that new layout.

It worked nicely as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace `ScrollView` with `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`

for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <!-- Place RecyclerView in here-->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```